# How to validate that a value is one of a set of acceptable values?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to compare the data of my barcode field with others in backoffice. How can I make this happen? I tried to use `@Assert\NotEqualTo`, but it did not work.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="barcode", type="string", length=38)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="La barcode est obligatoire.")
 * @Assert\NotEqualTo('5414975110018','3595890210860','3595890210532',
 * '5414975110001','3595890236426','3595890217197','3595890234613','3595890221552')
 *
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("barcode")
 * @Serializer\Expose()
 */
private $barcode;
```

Barcode must be one of these values

```
5414975110018
3595890210860
3595890210532
5414975110001
3595890236426
3595890217197
3595890234613
3595890221552
```

If the value is one of those, it's okay, but if not it should throw an error.

Comment: Are you trying to make sure it's unique? What is the outcome of the comparison?

Comment: I'm comparing my barcode data with those, and if its diferent throw an error

Comment: I'm a bit confused, sorry. So if it is unique, throw an error? Or throw an error if it is a duplicate?

Comment: I restate my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`Choice`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html) constraint for this.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="barcode", type="string", length=38)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="La barcode est obligatoire.")
 * @Assert\Choice({"5414975110018","3595890210860","3595890210532",
 * "5414975110001","3595890236426","3595890217197","3595890234613","3595890221552"})
 *
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("barcode")
 * @Serializer\Expose()
 */
```

`NotEqualTo` asserts that the value of the property *is not* equal to a certain value, but you want to assert that the value of the property *is* one of a set of values.